# How to periodically train and deploy new Machine Learning models on Google Cloud ML? How to automate this process?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-ml

I am successful in training models on GCP MLE, but now as new data is generated the model needs to be updated every couple of weeks and I am doing this manually, can someone kindly help me to automate this process.

My current architecture is I have data as csv files stored on GCS buckets, I manually run a script and train the model and export the newly trained model as webservice (via cloud endpoints) so users can query new data and get inference...

I would like to build a system where, every 2 weeks i will provide new csv files and a training job should be automatically triggered, and the new model should replace the old model for inference (I need everything to be automated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) to create a pipeline that runs periodically.

You can watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgrNTWQbABs) that explains how to do this for scikit learn models on Cloud ML Engine, but it's the same for TensorFlow. The notebook with the code can be found [here](https://github.com/rhaertel80/cloudai_samples/blob/master/ctr/ctr.ipynb).